# floor() behave strangely VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I was doing some coding and suddenly wondered with a strange behavior of floor(). The piece of line that caused error is mentioned below:

```
printf("%f",floor(310.96*100));
```

and the output was `31095.0000`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical [floating point issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326659/rounding-floats-with-non-exact-representation). The constant value `310.96` is not equally representable as a float number. Instead the closest float value representation is `310.9599914550781`.

You can try out your self [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/). Multipled that by `100` and truncated with `floor()` results in your `31095.0000`

Comment: but why the same is not happening for 310.95 or 310.97??

Comment: temp = 310.96*100;
floor(temp);

output is 31096......why it is not happening here?

Comment: If you check on the site I linked you can see that the closest floating point representation of `310.95` is `310.95001220703125` which greater than `310.95` and so `floor()` on the result of multiplication will (in this case) lead to the expected value. The general rule of thumb is, to not rely on exact flaoting point values but to understand their limitations and compensate for that, using ranges or appropriate rounding mechanisms

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are not 100% exact 310.96*100 might result in 31095.99999999... hence your result, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326659/rounding-floats-with-non-exact-representation)